# JavaScript documentations and reference?

Tags: javascript, manual, documents

I am having a lot of trouble finding a comprehensive set of documentation on javascript.  I am in the market for something that illustrates all of the members, methods, and data types that one would encounter in regular javascript programming.  For example, window, document, canvas, etc?

I can find lots of different tutorials for lots of different scenarios, and partial docs for some items,  but I am really in the market for actual programmer docs / manuals.  Does anyone know of a place on the web where I can find this?  Should I buy a book?

Comment: Check this out: http://es5.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [MDN - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).

Another great source of informations in the form of book is *[Eloquent JavaScript - A Modern Introduction to Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)* by Marijn Haverbeke.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the best JavaScript reference I've found on the web. It's not perfect, but 90% of the time it'll get you what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Comment: The reference proper is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Look no further. It's a wiki, so if you disagree with anything, edit it.
That is why hands down, I think it is the best resource.

Answer (score 0):

this could be useful, JavaScript guide from mozilla : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide